# Power BI embedded Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, powerbi

I am trying to integrate the power bi report with our asp.net mvc application. So I found this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-get-started-sample/ article and followed the steps. I have successfully created the workspace collection and generated the access keys. And I downloaded this https://github.com/Azure-Samples/power-bi-embedded-integrate-report-into-web-app/ sample application as specified in the article and ran the ProvisionSample contsole application. I selected the 5th step and provided the appropriate values for workspace collection name and access key and it throws the following error **"Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'"**. I looked at the audit logs and there is no error. Anyone have idea what causes for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue going on right now that is effecting some parts of the world. We are actively working on a fix.

Comment: Can you please give it another try?